# Proof that a finite separable extension has only finite many intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/F$ be finite separable extension. Is there any proof of the fact that there are only finitely many intermediate fields **without** using primitive element theorem or fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Comment: What's the motivation for not wanting to use either of those results? Considering the primitive element theorem is often stated as a finite extension has a primitive element if and only if there are a finite number of intermediate fields.

Comment: I want to prove that every finite sepeable extension has a primitive element directly from pimitive element theorem.

Comment: If one cannot use galois-theory, then why tag this galois-theory?

Comment: Because I thought  it is related to galois theory or can be used in galois theory.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mohan: Lang in his *Algebra* shows directly that a finite separable extension has a primitive element, and thus your result follows using the (stronger form of) The Primitive Element Theorem but no Galois Theory.  (This argument is replicated in $\S 8$ of my field theory notes: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf.)  I think this is *not* what you are looking for.  Could you amplify on why you want to avoid the Primitive Element Theorem and Galois Theory?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thank you very much for the link. My aim was to first prove the primitive element theorem for finite seperable extension then develop Galois theory from that. So, I was wondering if there is a very short proof of the fact a finite separable extension has only finitely many intermediate fields so that I could directly use the generalized primitive element theorem to prove that every finite sepeable extension has a primitive element.But the proof given in your note will also serve my purpose.

Answer (score 6):

I think of the following argumentation:
1) Let $K$ be a field and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $K^n$ has only finite many commutative unital subalgebras. The exact number is $B(n)$ - the $n$th Bell number.
2) Let $(K;L)$ be a separable extension. Then $L$ is separable as $K$-algebra. Thus, by tensoring a suitable splitting field $T$ for $L$ we get that $L\otimes T$ is isomorphic to $T^n$ for a suitable $n$. Hence - using 1) - $L\otimes T$ has only finite many commutative unital subalgebras.
3) The function $A\mapsto A\otimes L$ is injective defined on the commutative unital subalgebras of $L$.
4) Any commutative unital subalgebra of $L$ is a field, too.
Remark: Such algebras are called *futile* (with only finite many subalgebras) in the literature.

Comment: I don't think that 3) is correct. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.