# Two forms of the primitive element theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The primitive element theorem says that a finite separable extension is simple.  As I understand it, there is another primitive element theorem that states that an extension is simple iff there are finitely many intermediate fields. How can we deduce one from another?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297214/proof-that-a-finite-separable-extension-has-only-finite-many-intermediate-fields?rq=1), together with the above. A finite separable extension has only finitely many intermediate fields and hence is simple, i.e., monogeneous. The converse is clear. Both is mentioned at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: The question is indeed similar, but how to prove it using Galois theory?

Comment: In the [notes by Milne](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), chapter $5$ there is a "proof" (well, rather short). Would you mind to delete your edit? It is no longer valid.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand : 
if E/F is finite and separable, take the normal closure N/E/F, then N/F is Galois and so the intermediate fields of E/F which are also intermediate fields of N/F are in 1-1 correspondence with the subgroups of gal(N/F). but since this is a finite group it has only finitely many subgroups. Is that the right way to think?